# Trying to limit a RegEx to With or Without a space, including a '-' without spanning more than 2 words

Tags: regex

Thankyou in advance, complete noob at regular expressions here!

I'm searching HTML for a model number, for example.
"ER-A320"

Which can be expressed on a webpage as "ERA320", "ER A320" or "ER-A320"

I've got stuck at about this:

```
ER(\s*|.*)A320
```

I know this is completely wrong, the above expression isn't limited to 1 space, it will span a whole line unfortunately. e.g. "ER all the way to A320"

And won't pick up no-space e.g. "ERA320"

And addes a nasty '-' sign to the end.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This regular expression should work:

ER[ -]?A320

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you're looking for, are you looking for this exact model "ERA320" or "aaa000".

If you're looking for a pattern, use [this](http://regexr.com?2ur61):
`[A-Z]{2}[\s|\-]?A[0-9]{3}`, assuming you're looking for "XXANNN", X means `A-Z`, A means `A` and N is a number.

Otherwise use [this](http://regexr.com?2ur64):
`ER[\s-]?A320`.